# (more) safely preallocate numeric vector with NA default?

Tags: r

When preallocating a numeric vector with `numeric(length=1000)`, the default value is `0`, which can be dangerous or at least undesirable under certain circumstances.

How can we preallocate a numeric vector with `NA` values (rather than `0`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rep`:.

```
rep(NA_real_, 1000)
```

Comment: Very nice. I had never come across `NA_real_` before, but after seeing your answer, I also tried `rep(NA_character_, 1000)` to see what that would do, and it did as I suspected. i.e. `rep(NA_character_, 1000) %>% class` is `[1] "character"`

Comment: See `?\`NA\`` for more info